# Is it a Good practice to Save MySql Results to a new table for caching? Suggest some query optimization tips

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Now I am working with a little large data.
I have some doubts about handling million rows in mysql.

*Expecting some common tips for handling large data. So, I am not including more details about my database (If question is not clear, I can add more details).*

I have a self-referencing master table with more than 50000 rows. and I used below code for select parent details. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `junk`.`GetAncestry` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `junk`.`GetAncestry` (GivenID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE cm CHAR(1);
    DECLARE ch INT;

    SET rv = '';
    SET cm = '';
    SET ch = GivenID;
    WHILE ch > 0 DO
        SELECT IFNULL(parent_id,-1) INTO ch FROM
        (SELECT parent_id FROM pctable WHERE id = ch) A;
        IF ch > 0 THEN
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,cm,ch);
            SET cm = ',';
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN rv;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have a transaction table with million rows (now). and this table is growing faster.

When I using some complex queries for reports, that's very slow...

**My Questions** are as follows:

1. Is self-referencing tables is good?. If not, can you suggest any other ways? 
   ( I see This Link [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) But I feel this is more complicated.)
2. Is it a Good practice to Save MySQL Results to a table? ( I plan to create a new table with self-referencing table and it's path  )
3. Join with sub-queries are very slow, If sub-queries with calculations and group with sub-query fields. any suggestions?
4. Any other suggestions for handling large database and Query tuning?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There article you reference on managing hierarchical data is a very good article.  You should start there for advice.  Because MySQL basically has no support for hierarchical queries, self-referencing table structures should be used with caution.

Comment: Thank @GordonLinoff. I will careful next time.